# How to adjust "zoom" of image/div in a JQuery masked area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zooming, jquery-ui-draggable

I created this piece [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/WXBga/) using some tips I found here at StackExchange.  It works fine, butI'd like to create a slider or buttons to adjust the "zoom" on the draggable div, from the max you see here down to 100%. I can't seem to find any way to do it with Google, all the methods don't really apply here.

You'll notice it's not just an image, there will be DIVs there too (the yellow box in my example).

Here's a [Flash version](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/pages/the-inspector-thirtysix.asp) of the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at this plugin: http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/
It seems to have all the functionality you need.